# How to get country code from browser url and inject it in all page links

Tags: jquery, regex

suppose these are my address bar url http://localhost:53741/gb/default.aspx

OR http://localhost:53741/gb/default.aspx?id=1

OR http://localhost:53741/gb/part/part.aspx?id=1&vref=2010

so gb is the country code.

my default.aspx page has many hyperlinks and those looks like
http://localhost:53741/test1.aspx
http://localhost:53741/test2.aspx
http://localhost:53741/test3.aspx

now through jquery i want to get first country code from browser url which gb as per url and i need to inject that country code in all the hyperlinks of default.aspx page. so new links would be look like

http://localhost:53741/gb/test1.aspx
http://localhost:53741/gb/test2.aspx
http://localhost:53741/gb/test3.aspx

anyone can help me with jquery code sample how to achieve this. thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using a relative URL structure, so the links are all based on the current country code without needing to set it explicitly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry not very clear what you try to say. can you please come with a example.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the above problem. here i like to share my code the way i solved it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var segments = url.split('/');
        var countrycode = segments[1];

        var hyperLink = $("a:not(.noclass)");
        $.each(hyperLink, function (index, value) {
            var href = $(value).attr("href");
            $(value).attr("href", "/" + countrycode + (href == '/' ? '' : href));
            href = $(value).attr("href");
        });
    });
</script>
```

thanks